# Get non-sef URL in Joomla 4

Tags: php, joomla

Can you tell me how to echo the non-sef URL in Joomla 4. The code below and other answers on here work only in Joomla 3:

```
<?php
$router = JSite::getRouter();//      get router
$query = $router->parse(JUri::getInstance()); // Get the real joomla query as an array - parse current joomla link
$url = 'index.php?'.JUri::getInstance()->buildQuery($query);
echo $url;
?>
```

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] and ask your Joomla questions there.

Comment: No thanks. I will ask questions here

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

Change JSite to JApplicationSite